# Conditionally require question in Survey123 if an image is submitted

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-survey123

In Survey123 Connect (Desktop), is it possible to conditionally require a question only if the field worker has submitted a photo of an asset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on whether you are creating the forms with the web app or the Survey123 Connect desktop app.

If you are using the desktop app `${your_photo_question}!=''` in the "Relevant" column should do the trick.

Comment: Works perfect in conjunction with "Required=Yes" on the question field (naturally). Much appreciated.